# Will this combination of robots.txt and .htaccess rules block indexing of certain file types?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, robots.txt

I'm working on a WordPress site that has a login portal where users can access 'classified' documents in pdf,doc and a few other formats. The files are uploaded via the media manager, so are always stored in /wp-content/uploads

I need to make sure these file types are not shown in search results. I've made some rules in .htaccess and robots.txt that I *think* will work, but it's very hard to test, so I was hoping someone could glance over them and let me know if they'll do what I'm expecting them to or not. One thing in particular I wasn't sure of: would the `disallow: /wp-content/` stop the `x-robots-tag` from being seen?

.htaccess - under `# end Wordpress`

```
# do not index specified file types
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.(doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|ppt|pptx)$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

robots.txt - complete

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: /wp-
Disallow: /growers-portal
Disallow: /growers-portal/
Disallow: /grower_posts
Disallow: /grower_posts/
Sitemap: http://www.pureaussiepineapples.com.au/sitemap_index.xml
```

Comment: Your htaccess seems to be good.. You can check your robots.txt file in the following link https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those stop anyone reading your "classified" documents. To do that you really want to restrict access based on logged in users.

The robots tag will keep the files out of the search results.

However,  robots.txt does not stop files being in the search results. Google takes that directive to say they can't read the file but they can still include it in the index.

This causes an interesting scenario. Your robots.txt stops Google reading the robots tag so does not know you want it out of the index.

So, if you're not going to physically control access to the files I would use the robots tag but not robots.txt directives.

Comment: Thanks. I wondered if that might be the case. Ill get rid of the robots.txt part.